# Send real time data from Android to Server

Tags: android, web-services, server

I'm building an Android application. So with this app I get the data from device throught bluetooth.

For this, I don't have problems. Now I want to send in real time the data at the server. But I don't know what type of Web Service I must building, and I don't know what library of Android that I must used.

Can we help me ?

Comment: did you try firebase realtime database https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIo8CS-f6-3AIVlKmWCh0QFwnhEAAYASAAEgIiKvD_BwE

Comment: I must send this data at the server with T.SQL database

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people ask the questions about real time data transfer. There are few technologies I am aware of, and may help other developers

1- [Socket.iO](https://socket.io)

Socket.IO enables real-time bidirectional event-based communication.
It works on every platform, browser or device, focusing equally on reliability and speed.

2- [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/)

EventBus is a publish/subscribe event bus for Android and Java.

3- [MQTT Server](http://mqtt.org)

It was designed as an extremely lightweight publish/subscribe messaging transport.

4- [Lightsteamer](https://lightstreamer.com)
Lightstreamer is your one-stop shop for push notifications, data streaming, and realtime messaging. Power web, mobile, and IoT apps with realtime data.

It should be noted that lightstreamer is not free